# sculpt mode not working grab tool and sculpt tool topology is weird

Tags: sculpting

sculpt mode not working grab tool and sculpt tool topology is weird

[image]

instead of having a polished topology i get weird artifacts

blend file here

https://workupload.com/file/P5ZAMspyH6Z

i tried remesh too to 0.0480

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the *Cavity* option (not sure why it makes this mess though):

[image]

Comment: thanks , sorry again